# Slack slash commands - Variable/Parameters

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm integrating `slack` with `jenkins` to use `slash` commands and want to know if `slash` commands have `variables`

What I want to do is something like this;

`/this_word_should_be_in_the_url word`

and the be able to use `word` in the `URL` the slash command will call.

On their page they have something like `/weather 94070`

Do I have access to the `94070` and somehow set is as a `query` parameter for the URL.

Is this possible?
Can't find any documentation of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You will have access to the `word` as per the example that you mentioned.

So for example, if you have the following:

`/this_word_should_be_in_the_url word`

Then there will be an additional query parameter named `text` that will contain everything else after the slash command. If you just have one parameter then it should be simple to just trim and use the `text` query parameter but if you have multiple words and need to split them into something more meaningful, then you might have to use some regex or simple string split function.

It is documented at [How do commands work](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#how_do_commands_work). In this section they have provided the various query parameters that will get passed to your Slash Command External URL. For the weather example, the data posted as per the documentation is:

`token=gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
command=/weather
text=94070
response_url=https://hooks.slack.com/commands/1234/5678`

Notice the `text` parameter in the above list.

Comment: what if I have multiple words? example `/lyft ride <pickup_address> to <dropoff_address>` how can I access `pickup_address` and `dropoff_address` or do I have to do string manipulation on my side?

Comment: and everything will be under `request.text` correct?

Comment: Yes it should. Try it out.

Comment: Following your response, and some others, I ended up writing a small NodeJS script to take the slash command and call jenkins. https://github.com/victorbello/jenkins-trigger